# query grandchildren taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, taxonomy

I have a function that queries the children of each taxonomy terms, I'd also like to query the children of these children terms too, my markup is as follows:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms("wpsc_product_category");
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach( get_terms( 'wpsc_product_category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 ) ) as $parent_term ) { ?>

        <div id="sub-header-menu-<?php echo $parent_term->slug; ?>" class="sub-header-menu-content">
            <ul class="sub-header-menu">
            <?php foreach( get_terms( 'wpsc_product_category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $parent_term->term_id ) ) as $child_term ) { ?>
            <li data-hook="<?php echo $child_term->slug; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/products/<?php echo $child_term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $child_term->name; ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <?php }

} ?>
```

Is this possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `child_of` at your second foreach, [see the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

> child_of
>
> (integer) Get all descendents of this term. Default is 0. Note: the difference between child_of and parent is that where **parent only gets direct children** of the parent term (ie: 1 level down), **child_of gets all descendants** (as many levels as are available)

So in your case your second foreach will look like this:

```
<?php foreach( get_terms( 'wpsc_product_category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'child_of' => $parent_term->term_id ) ) as $child_term ) { ?>
```

You can use the returning value `parent` in a conditional statement to detect on what "level" the term is. Of course you can do this also with one foreach.

Comment: thanks for your answer, very very close here. Although this `foreach` is display all terms, parent, children and grand-children. I was hoping to displaying the grand-children as a sub-menu within the relevant child term if possible?

Comment: @user1374796 Have a look at my latest edit, use the returning value `parent` [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10332361/3157038).